# This is the most difficult question I could get without using mass point geometry

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, affine-geometry

In triangle ABC, points D and E are on sides BC and CA respectively, and points F and G are on side AB with G between F and B.  BE intersects CF at point O_1 and BE intersects DG at point O_2.  If FG = 1, AE = AF = DB = DC = 2, and BG = CE = 3, compute $\tfrac{O_1O_2}{BE}$.

I couldn't think of other method to solve this(besides, iI don't know mass point geometry) will choose the most reasonable answer!

Answer is in problem 3 in this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_point_geometry

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't put things like "Thanks in advance?" in the title -- it clutters the main page. The rest of the title should also be more concise and descriptive, usually not a complete sentence but a  noun phrase or a short question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with vectors in the plane. Choose $B$ as origin and put $BD=:d$, $BG=:g$. Then from the given data we see that $BF={4g\over3}$,  $BA=2g$, $BC=2d$ and $BE={4d+6g\over5}$. Obviously $BO_2={1\over2}BE={2d+3g\over5}$.

It remains to compute the point $O_1$. Now
$$BO_1=BC+s\ CF\quad{\rm and}\quad BO_1=t\ BE$$
for some $s>0$ and some $t>{1\over2}$. It follows that
$$2d + s\Bigl({4g\over3}-2d\Bigr)= t{4d+6g\over 5}\ .$$
Since the vectors $d$ and $g$ are linearly independent this equation determines $s$ and $t$ uniquely.

The rest is easy. Actually we only need the value of $t$, and the final result is $t-{1\over2}$.